# Google Maps jquery gomap maxzoom and minzoom is not working

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm using goMap() jquery.gomap-1.3.2.min.js (http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/) on this site: http://www.airzone.ch/de_CH/reisen.cfm.

I would like to have a function that the user cannot zoom to much out, not more than zoom function 1. I inserted minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 10. But it's not working. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks Bettina

```
function showMapFull(){

            $("#map")
                .show()
                .goMap({
                    address: 'Tchad',
                    zoom: 2,
                    minZoom: 1,
                    maxZoom: 10,
                    maptype: 'SATELLITE',

                    markers : [

                            {
                                latitude: 44.96,
                                longitude: 35.2405556,
                                html: {
                                    content: 'xxxxxxx'
                                },
                                group: 'mapinfo6',
                                id: 'mapinfo6',
                                className: 'BubbleWindow'
                            },

                            {



                    ],
                    icon: '/templates/airzone/media/img/design/icon_ferien.png',
                    mapTypeControl: false,

                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        position: 'TOP_LEFT',
                        style: 'SMALL'
                    }


                });

    };

    $(function() {

        showMapFull();

        $(".ferien_elem").on('mouseenter', function(){
            google.maps.event.trigger( $($.goMap.mapId).data( $(this).data('mapinfo') ), 'click' );
        });

    })
```

Comment: It's not listening to you maxZoom either - are you sure these are configurable parameters of the goMap() plugin?

Comment: No i'm not sure. I was looking in http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/. But couldn't find. But maybe someone knows how to make it.